# Linux freezes after inserting module

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel

I have a linux module printing out hello world using `__initdata`, when I insert using `insmod` and view the module using `dmesg` the OS freezes and nothing is working, cluding mouse, keyboard and the virtual consols. There seems to be errors, but couldn't make what they were in dmesg, here is my code and the dmesg. I am using fedora with `3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64` kernel

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>

static int hello2_data __initdata = 2;

static int __init hello2_init(void){

    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Hello2 module- Hello World %d!\n", hello2_data);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello2_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Hello2 module- Goodbye World %d!!\n", hello2_data);
}

module_init(hello2_init);
module_exit(hello2_exit);
```

[image: dmesg output]

Comment: That stack trace says `rmmod` bugged out, not `insmod`. Please recheck exactly what happened, and the think about what using `initdata` stuff in an `_exit` routine should do.

Comment: *__initdata* will be freed after module init. Do not use it out of *__init* function.

Comment: Alright thank you. Any reason why it would freeze up everything?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949943/module-programming-in-linux).